# Export datatable to csv using FileHelpers in memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, export-to-csv, filehelpers

I want to export a .NET datatable to csv using FileHelpers.
The CommonEngine.DataTableToCsv doesn't cover my needs as it only writes to a file, I need it to be in memory.

I found a post which was using but the accepted answer CommonEngine.DataTableToCsv

```
DelimitedClassBuilder cb = new DelimitedClassBuilder("DataRow", ",", table);
Type t = cb.CreateRecordClass();
DelimitedFileEngine engine = new DelimitedFileEngine(t);
```

Can help would be awesome.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with the FileHelpers library, but is [`engine.WriteFile(file, records);`](https://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/M_FileHelpers_FileHelperEngine_1_WriteFile.htm) not what you want?

Comment: Isn't there an overload that returns a string? Perhaps a WriteString method? It's an open source library, did you bother looking at the source code before asking on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the issue; [according to the docs there](https://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/Methods_T_FileHelpers_FileHelperEngine_1.htm) there are `WriteString` and `WriteStream` methods too.